# $rootscope not holding value

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

I am using the following code to store username ('pqr') value in rootscope but it is scoped by $http.get mehtod

```js
angular.module('myApp').run(function ($rootScope,$http) {
    $rootScope.username = 'abc';
    $http.get('/api/getuser')
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log("logged in user is: "+data);
            $rootScope.username = data;
        });
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    });
    console.log("logged in user after setting: " + $rootScope.username);
});
```

The console log outputs are:

```
logged in user is: pqr
logged in user after setting: abc
```

How can I set the $rootScope.username to pqr out of scope of $http.get method

EDIT: Added closing brackets.

Comment: Its async..... you are logging before setting.

Comment: Your code snippet is missing brackets

Comment: Yes, I was counting on to assume the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be closed, because its an async issue... run this code and you will see.

```
angular.module('myApp').run(function ($rootScope,$http) {
 $rootScope.username = 'abc';
 var $promise = $http.get('/api/getuser')
    .success(function(data) {
      console.log("logged in user is: "+data);
      $rootScope.username = data;
    });
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {

 });
 $promise.then(function(){
     console.log("logged in user after setting: "+$rootScope.username);
 });
```